# Add label to all emails in inbox to who I replied?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

How would I go about Google Apps scripting to apply a label to all emails in my inbox to which I had replied?

I was looking at Gmail's filters but couldn't figure out how to construct this filter.

Answer (score 1):

How about this sample script? Although I looked for the sample script for this situation, unfortunately I couldn't also find. So I created this as my try, because I also wanted to use this script. The concept of this script is as follows.

- When there are more than 2 messages in a thread, there might be a possibility to have replied.
- For more than 2 messages in a thread

  - The email address of "from" for the 1st message is the sender's address.
  - When the email address of "to" of after 2nd messages is the same to that of "from" of 1st one, it is indicates that the thread was replied by owner.

I prepared a sample script from above concept.

### Sample script :

In order to use this sample, please input `label`. When run `myFunction()`, the `label` is added to the mails that owner replied in Inbox.

```
function myFunction() {
  var label = "temp"; // Please input a label you want to use.

  var threadId = "";
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  thread.forEach(function(th) {
    th.getMessages().forEach(function(msg) {
      var mm = msg.getThread().getMessages();
      if (mm.length > 0) {
        var temp = [];
        mm.forEach(function(m) {
          var re = /<(\w.+)>/g;
          var from  = m.getFrom();
          var to = m.getTo();
          temp.push({
            from: from.match(re) ? re.exec(from)[1] : from,
            to: to.match(re) ? re.exec(to)[1] : to
          });
        });
        if (temp.length > 1 && threadId != th.getId()) {
          if (temp.filter(function(e){return temp[0].from == e.to}).length > 0) {
            var rr = th.addLabel(GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label));
            Logger.log("Label '%s' was added to threadId %s.", label, rr.getId())
          }
          threadId = th.getId();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

### Note :

- The mails that it was replied to the mails that owner sent are not retrieved.
- If you use this sample script, please test using for example `var th = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 50);`, and understand the flow. And please run above script.

### Reference :

- [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
- [addLabel()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#addLabel(GmailLabel))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit 1 :

In order to use this sample script, please enable [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) at [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) and API console. The flow of it is as follows.

#### Enable Gmail API v1 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Gmail API v1

#### [Enable Gmail API at API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/overview)

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "Gmail". And click Gmail API.
  - Click Enable button.
  - If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

If now you are opening the script editor with the script for using Gmail API, you can enable Gmail API for the project by accessing this URL https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/overview

#### Sample script :

This script adds a label to only replied email. `addLabel` of GmailApp adds a label to only the thread. This cannot add the label to the specific messages in the thread. So I used Gmail API. When you use this script, please modify `label`, `userId` and `thread` for your environment.

```
function myFunction() {
  var label = "#####"; // Please input a label you want to use.
  var userId = "me"; // If you use this script by yourself, userId is "me".
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(); // In this setting, all mails in Inbox are retrieved. If you want to use the specific mails, please modify here.

  var threadId = "";
  thread.forEach(function(th) {
    th.getMessages().forEach(function(msg) {
      var mm = msg.getThread().getMessages();
      if (mm.length > 0) {
        var temp = [];
        mm.forEach(function(m) {
          var re = /<(\w.+)>/g;
          var from  = m.getFrom();
          var to = m.getTo();
          temp.push({
            from: from.match(re) ? re.exec(from)[1] : from,
            to: to.match(re) ? re.exec(to)[1] : to,
            threadId: th.getId(),
            messageId: m.getId()
          });
        });
        if (temp.length > 1 && threadId != th.getId()) {
          if (temp.filter(function(e){return temp[0].from == e.to}).length > 0) {
            var receivedFrom = temp.filter(function(e){return e.threadId == e.messageId})[0].from;
            temp.filter(function(e){return e.to == receivedFrom}).forEach(function(e){
              Gmail.Users.Messages.modify(
                {"addLabelIds": [Gmail.Users.Labels.list(userId).labels.filter(function(e){return e.name == label})[0].id]},
                userId,
                e.messageId
              );
              Logger.log("Label '%s' was added to messageId '%s'.", label, e.messageId)
            });
          }
          threadId = th.getId();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

#### Note :

- In this sample script, `var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();` to retrieve threads is used. This means that all threads in Inbox are retrieved. So please modify this if you want to retrieve the specific threads.

### Edit 2 :

The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Received an email from user A.
2. You reply to the received email.

   - The label is added to this message.
3. Received a reply from user A

   - If you replied to the 1st message, the label is added to this message.

#### Script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var label = "#####"; // Please input a label you want to use.
  var userId = "me"; // If you use this script by yourself, userId is "me".
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(); // In this setting, all mails in Inbox are retrieved. If you want to use the specific mails, please modify here.

  var threadId = "";
  thread.forEach(function(th) {
    th.getMessages().forEach(function(msg) {
      var mm = msg.getThread().getMessages();
      if (mm.length > 0) {
        var temp = [];
        mm.forEach(function(m) {
          var re = /<(\w.+)>/g;
          var from  = m.getFrom();
          var to = m.getTo();
          temp.push({
            from: from.match(re) ? re.exec(from)[1] : from,
            to: to.match(re) ? re.exec(to)[1] : to,
            threadId: th.getId(),
            messageId: m.getId()
          });
        });
        if (temp.length > 1 && threadId != th.getId()) {
          if (temp.filter(function(e){return temp[0].from == e.to}).length > 0) {
            var receivedFrom = temp.filter(function(e){return e.threadId == e.messageId})[0].from;
            if (temp.filter(function(e){return e.to == receivedFrom}).length > 0) {
              temp.forEach(function(e, i){
                if (i > 0) {
                  Gmail.Users.Messages.modify(
                    {"addLabelIds": [Gmail.Users.Labels.list(userId).labels.filter(function(e){return e.name == label})[0].id]},
                    userId,
                    e.messageId
                  );
                  Logger.log("Label '%s' was added to messageId '%s'.", label, e.messageId)
                }
              });              
            }
          }
          threadId = th.getId();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

### Edit 3:

> 1. A sends email to me.
> 2. I respond and keep this email in my inbox.
> 3. A responds to my response.
> 4. A’s response comes as a second email because conversations view is off.
>
> I am not going to respond again to his email from 4.
>   I am running the script. 1. Should be labelled but 4. Should not be labelled

I could know that you want to add the label to only 2 for above situation. In this case, my 2nd sample works fine. But you said this script is not what you want. I thought that the relation between thread ID and message IDs may be different from my consideration. So I prepared a sample script for retrieving message IDs in a thread ID. Before you use this script, please do above your scenario. After this, please run this script, and retrieve message IDs and the thread ID.  Please tell me the result and the message ID you want to add the label.

This script retrieves messages in a thread ID. messageId, from, to and subject are retrieved for the information of each message.

```
function myFunction() {
  var result = [];
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var threadId = "";
  thread.forEach(function(th) {
    th.getMessages().forEach(function(msg) {
      var mm = msg.getThread().getMessages();
      if (mm.length > 1) {
        var ids = {threadId: msg.getThread().getId()}
        var mids = [];
        mm.forEach(function(m) {
          mids.push({
            messageId: m.getId(),
            from: m.getFrom(),
            to: m.getTo(),
            subject: m.getSubject()
          });
        });
        ids.message = mids;
        if (threadId != th.getId()) {
          result.push(ids);
        }
      }
      threadId = th.getId();
    });
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result))
}
```

### Edit 4 :

This script adds a label to a replied message. This script supposes the following situation.

1. You receive an email from user "A" in Inbox. This is message "1". At this time, a thread is created.
2. You reply to user "A" for message "1". The replied message is message "2". This message is added to the created thread.
3. You receive an email from user "A" as the reply. This message is message "3". This message is also added to the created thread.

For above situation, this script adds a label to only message "2".

#### Script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var label = "temp"; // Please input a label you want to use.
  var userId = "me"; // If you use this script by yourself, userId is "me".
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(); // In this setting, all mails in Inbox are retrieved. If you want to use the special mails, please modify here.

  var threadId = "";
  thread.forEach(function(th) {
    th.getMessages().forEach(function(msg) {
      var mm = msg.getThread().getMessages();
      if (mm.length > 1) {
        var temp = [];
        mm.forEach(function(m) {
          var re = /<(\w.+)>/g;
          var from  = m.getFrom();
          var to = m.getTo();
          temp.push({
            from: from.match(re) ? re.exec(from)[1] : from,
            to: to.match(re) ? re.exec(to)[1] : to,
            threadId: th.getId(),
            messageId: m.getId()
          });
        });
        if (temp.length > 1 && threadId != th.getId()) {
          var ar = temp.filter(function(e){return temp[0].from == e.to});
          if (ar.length > 0) {
            if (ar.length > 1) ar.splice(1, ar.length - 1);
            ar.forEach(function(e){
              Gmail.Users.Messages.modify(
                {"addLabelIds": [Gmail.Users.Labels.list(userId).labels.filter(function(e){return e.name == label})[0].id]},
                userId,
                e.messageId
              );
              Logger.log("Label '%s' was added to messageId '%s'.", label, e.messageId)
            });
          }
          threadId = th.getId();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

#### Note :

- When you use this script, in this script, `var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();` is used for retrieving messages. This means that messages in Inbox are retrieved. If you want to retrieve in other places, please modify this.

### Edit 5 :

```
function myFunction() {
  var label = "temp"; // Please input a label you want to use.
  var userId = "me"; // If you use this script by yourself, userId is "me".
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(); // In this setting, all mails in Inbox are retrieved. If you want to use the special mails, please modify here.

  var threadId = "";
  thread.forEach(function(th) {
    th.getMessages().forEach(function(msg) {
      var mm = msg.getThread().getMessages();
      if (mm.length > 1) {
        var temp = [];
        mm.forEach(function(m) {
          var re = /<(\w.+)>/g;
          var from  = m.getFrom();
          var to = m.getTo();
          temp.push({
            from: from.match(re) ? re.exec(from)[1] : from,
            to: to.match(re) ? re.exec(to)[1] : to,
            threadId: th.getId(),
            messageId: m.getId()
          });
        });

        Logger.log("temp : %s", temp) // Added

        if (temp.length > 1 && threadId != th.getId()) {
          var ar = temp.filter(function(e){return temp[0].from == e.to});

          Logger.log("ar : %s", ar) // Added

          if (ar.length > 0) {
            if (ar.length > 1) ar.splice(1, ar.length - 1);
            ar.forEach(function(e){
              Gmail.Users.Messages.modify(
                {"addLabelIds": [Gmail.Users.Labels.list(userId).labels.filter(function(e){return e.name == label})[0].id]},
                userId,
                e.messageId
              );
              Logger.log("Label '%s' was added to messageId '%s'.", label, e.messageId)
            });
          }
          threadId = th.getId();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not fully functional though. I ran the script and it added the label to an email in my inbox to which I definitely did not reply yet. All my emails in inbox are individual messages because I disabled conversations view. Could that be the issue here?

Comment: @orschiro I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I would like to confirm about your situation. The label is added to the mails that you just received without replying yet? In my environment, I couldn't reproduce your situation. When I have an email which just received email without replying, the script doesn't add the label. When I replied it, the label is added. So can I ask you about the detail situation?

Comment: Disable conversations view in your settings. Then test your script with two emails that normally would be shown in conversations view (have the same subject). Reply to one but not to the other. In my case the "replied" label is added to both and not only the one I actually replied.

Comment: @orschiro Can I ask you about the test situation? Two mails you tested are the received mails from other users or other mail address? I also tested this situation. The script added the label to only the thread of replied mail. In gmail, when a email is received, a thread is created. When user replies the email, the replied email is created in the same thread. My script uses this situation. I think that my test may be the difference from yours. Also I think that this problem is the chance to modify the script. So I would like to solve this. But I'm sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts! Look at [this screencast](https://youtu.be/MYJjWTmP8tU). The label got applied to both emails BUT I only replied to the first from `10:20` and not `10:23`.

Comment: @orschiro Thank you for your movie. I saw it. It seems that both 2 emails are in the same thread. If you received an email from an user, and when you replied to the email, the replied email and first received email have the lavel. This is the work of the script. I had understand this is what you want. But it seems that this is the difference from yours. Can I ask you about what you want to do? You received an email from an user. For this email, you replied to the email. In this situation, which mail do you want to give the label? I thought one step closer to the solution by your movie.

Comment: I want to attach the label only to the mail to which I responded which in my video was the first. Not the second. Does that make sense? :-)

Comment: @orschiro I updated my answer by your comments. Please confirm it. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I tested your latest script. It runs without issues but doesn't work. Check [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/AWSXCir.png). I replied to the email from `10:19`. But it doesn't add the label which I have chosen. I didn't reply to `10:22` so correct that no label has been added to this one.

Comment: @orschiro I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about your situation? I supposes the following situation from your comments. You received an email from an user. And then, you replied for the received email. And you want to give a label to only the replied mail. Is this situation correct? My understanding is wrong. Can you show me the situation? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: No worries! We are getting there. :-) Let's do the following. Can you write me an email to robert@sheetgo.com? I am going to reply. This email should be labeled. You then reply back to me. This time I am not going to reply. Hence, this second email from you in my inbox should not be labeled!

Comment: @orschiro I could understand the situation what you want. But this modified script is for the situation. So I'm a bit confusing. I would like to confirm it again. As a sample, I sent an email to your mail address. Please confirm it.

Comment: Just replied to your email! :-)

Comment: @orschiro I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I got it. I replied.

Comment: Still not functional. I tried the last script from your answer and went to explain it again [in this video](https://youtu.be/Rpa9aOSm044). Please let me know if you understand.

Comment: @orschiro Thank you for the information. I saw your youtube. When you run manually the flow for giving a label to messages, I think that the thread ID is only one. So can you tell me about message IDs in a thread ID? And please tell me message IDs you want to give the label and mail address of "from" and "to"? Of course, the mail address is for example "me" and "user A". By this and your youtube, I would like to understand the situation you want. I'm sorry for taking your time.

Comment: @orschiro Thank you for your reply. I saw it. I think we were one step closer to the goal. I sent one question for it. Please confirm it.

Comment: I confirmed your question :-)

Comment: @orschiro I could confirm it. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @orschiro I updated my answer. Please confirm it. This update reflected our discussions. I confirmed that this script works fine in my environment and other 2 accounts. So when this didn't work, please confirm your environment.

Comment: I ran the script from edit 4 but it's not adding any label. Also no error. How can I debug this now?

Comment: @orschiro I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I had prepared a sample script for retrieving the message IDs in a thread, by this, I had thought that I could confirm your environment. In my environment and other 2 accounts, my updated script works fine. So it is considered that your environment is different from those accounts. I would like to solve your problem, but in this situation, it is difficult to do it. Although if I could confirm directly your environment, it may find the reason, I think that this may be difficult for you. Can I ask you about your comments?

Comment: Hello Tanaike, I appreciate all your efforts with this script!I am currently short on time debugging this further. Let's leave this for now. Maybe someone else can jump in and help testing!

Comment: @orschiro I'm really sorry I couldn't help you.

Comment: @orschiro Now I noticed that when it replies to the received email, if it is replied by "send and archive", the thread with the received message and replied message is move from Inbox. So the messages cannot be retrieved by ``getInboxThreads()``. By this, it seems that this script doesn't work. Please click "send" button when you reply message. And I added ``Logger.log()`` for debugging. Please confirm the updated answer. If you can do, please tell me the Log by running this script for debug, after you received a message and replied it.